# How can I create a underline hover effect for my navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar that has an effect when the user hovers over one of the sections. I have already made the navbar, but I am having trouble constructing the underline hover effect. I want it so when the user hovers, a line appears at the bottom indicating they can click it. How can I create this effect? Here is the code I am using, thanks.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   body{
    min-height: 200vh;
    background-color: blue;;
   }
   header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header.sticky{
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header .logo{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul li a{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a{
    color: #000;
    font-family: serif;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class=""></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
header ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

By the way, there's no need to define the font for every element - declare it on the `body` and everything will inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   body{
    min-height: 200vh;
    background-color: blue;;
   }
   header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header.sticky{
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header .logo{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: serif;
   }
   header ul li a{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    font-family: serif;
   }
/* On Hover */
header ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
/* On Hover END */
   header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a{
    color: #000;
    font-family: serif;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class=""></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```